# How to push a single value with Array.push in a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

```js
const y = [...Array(2)].map(() => Array(3).fill([]));
console.log('Before: ', JSON.stringify(y)); 
// Before:  [[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]]]
y[0][1].push("foo");
console.log('After: ', JSON.stringify(y)); 
// After:  [[["foo"],["foo"],["foo"]],[[],[],[]]]
```

Why is "foo" inserted three times ? And how can I insert "foo" only in the first one i.e. How can I get

```
// After:  [[["foo"],[],[]],[[],[],[]]]
```

Comment: you fill the array with the same object reference.

Comment: You can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Description